# How to import data from array into sqlite3 table

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

So I know how to import data into database, but my problem is with the data itself. My array looks like this:

```
customers = ['name surname', 'name surname', 'name surname', 'name surname', 'name surname',
             'name surname', 'name surname', 'name surname', 'name surname', 'name surname',
             'name surname', 'name surname',...]
```

The array consists of first names and surnames, but they are in the same field. My database has 3 columns:
**[Id, first_name, last_name]**
Is there a way to import it into database without creating arrays just to hold first names and surnames ? 
Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong about creating a new array?

```
new_customers = [name.split() for name in customers]

# Establish your db connection = con and cursor = c here

# assuming your db has id set to NOT NULL so it increments autmatically
insert_statement = "INSERT INTO your_table (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?)"

for name in new_customers:
    c.execute(insert_statement, (name[0], name[1]))
```

(edit) or just:

```
for customer in customers:
    first_name, last_name = customer.split()
    c.execute(insert_statement, (first_name, last_name))
```

Comment: Using `executemany()` is probably better.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I completely forgot about split(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
dataframe=pd.DataFrame(customers, columns=["Name"]) 
dummyval = dataframe["Name"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True) #This splits the string when space is encountered 

dataframe["FName"]= dummyval[0] 
dataframe["LName"]= dummyval[1] 
dataframe.drop(columns =["Name"], inplace = True) 

#Connection
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="host",
  user="uname",
  password="pass",
  database="db"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
for i in range(len(dataframe)): #looping through the df 
    sql = "INSERT INTO customers (fname, lname) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    val = (dataframe['FName'][i], dataframe['LName'][i])
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit()
```